# java observers causing cyclic inheritance

Tags: java, compiler-errors, observer-pattern, cyclic

Suppose I have two classes: `A` with property `A.a`, `B` with property `B.b`.

Some properties in `A` depend on `B.b`, but `A.a` does not depend on `B.b`.

Some properties in `B` depend on `A.a`, but `B.b` does not depend on `A.a`.

I would like `A` to be notified of changes in `B.b`, and `B` to be notified of changes in `A.a`.  If I use the standard observer pattern:

```
public class A implements B.Observer {..}

public class B implements A.Observer {..}
```

I get a compiler error:

> cyclic inheritance involving B (or A).

I realize that this could cause an infinite loop in general, but it doesn't in this case. For example, if `A.a` changes, `A` would notify `B`. But since `A.a` has no effect on `B.b`, there is no return notification to `A` and no cycle.

I appreciate that `Java` is trying to prevent general problems, but I need to implement this somehow. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve something with inheritance that shouldn't be solved with inheritance. I'd look to using a general notification interface, perhaps like a PropertyChangeListener, but otherwise use composition.

Comment: If you remove B.Observer from B, and A.Obseserver from A, this should solve the problem

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `B.Observer` and `A.Observer`. The standard observer pattern has only one `Observer` interface implemented by all observers.

Comment: I need two observer interfaces.  One for changes in A.a and the other for changes in B.b.  I have found that I can implement this in an application-specific manner without formally declaring observer interfaces (e.g. A uses a method in B to notify it that A.a has changed). I can then remove the"implements" declarations and eliminate the compiler errors.  The publish-subscribe approach in the accepted answer is a more general way to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [publish-subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) where each of your classes is both a publisher and a subscriber.

```
interface Publisher {
    void addSubscriber(Subscriber sub);
}

interface Subscriber {
    void handle (Object event);
}

class A implements Publisher, Subscriber {...}
class B implements Publisher, Subscriber {...}
```

If you don't mind using some JavaFX techniques, then you should look into [properties and binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) which will allow you to something similar to what you already have but this time no compiler errors